# Can I have an option to turn off default page under public folder?

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I recently purchased a portal and I can get it into my website as outsourcing company provided codes.

I'm not a web developer so I don't know much about web programming.

After I put the files ( assets,fonts,scripts,styles, etc) under public folder, it does work fine, but it's set up as a default page. I guess it's because under public.

My question is that is there a way to turn off default page even though index.html file is under public folder?? so the website is working as it's been and the new file will be under subdirectory  like  mywebsite.com/career/

I'm using ruby 2.3.7 and rails 5.2.0.
The website is hosted on Heroku if these are helpful.

Comment: I am not sure I understood you correctly, but you probably should put the codes into `public/career` folder (create it first if it doesn't exist). Then it will be available at `mywebsite.com/career/` and the old Rails website will work as it's been.

Comment: If you're sticking a load of static files in the public folder anyway, why run rails at all?

Comment: > is that is there a way to turn off default page even though index.html. No there isn't. I'm a rails contributor and that is pretty hard coded behavior. Instead you can rename it to something like `_index.html` which would prevent it from being loaded by default until someone visits yourapp.herokuapp.com/_index.html. In short, you need to change the name of the file.

Comment: @Scheneems  thanks for the tip.